# Shadow blur efect in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, shadow

How can I create this shadow blur in the top and bottom of the Widget that appears to be on top of the list?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to wrap your child with Stack and a mask:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    //_yourWidget(),
                Opacity(
                  opacity: 0.5,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 50.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        colors: <Color>[
                          Colors.black,
                          Colors.transparent,
                          Colors.transparent,
                          Colors.black,
                        ],
                        stops: [
                          0,
                          0.2,
                          0.8,
                          1,
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: I had to change the stops to: 0.3, 0.3, 0.8, 0.8, but it worked perfectly, thank you so much

Comment: little tweak makes better, good to go!